# ¿Para que sirve case of?

Tags: delphi

Me he estado preguntando como hacer un buen uso del case of pero no sé como implementarlo correctamente ni cuando es necesario hacerlo. Me gustaría que alguien me explicase como funciona.

Comment: Hola Jose. Tu pregunta es muy amplia. Lo que debes hacer es leer la documentacion al respecto. Una vez intentes implementarlo, si tienes fallos o problemas puedes presentar aqui el codigo con su explicacion para que te ayudemos a resolver esas dudas puntuales. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Para explicarlo de forma sencilla, el CASE...OF te da la posibilidad (en muchos casos) de evitar la sentencia IF...THEN cuando tienes muchas anidaciones o muchas condiciones.
Una premisa para utilizarlo es que la expresión de selección debe ser un elemento numérico, ordinal, enumerado,... pero no puede ser cualquier tipo.

Un par de links con ejemplos y una explicación sencilla puede ser esta página:
http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Case

O la propia DocWiki de Embarcadero:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Case_Statements

Comment: Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,

El uso que se le da al case es:
Cuando tienes una variable que puede tener distintos valores y para cada uno de ellos tienes que interpretarlo de forma diferente, ejemplo:
Tengo una variable numérica que cuando es 0 tengo que sumar, 1 tengo que restar,  2 tengo que multiplicar y 3 tengo que dividir, para esto, en vez de usar una cadena de 'if' usaremos el case.

Te dejo aquí un pare de enlaces para que veas ejemplos y ver como se usa:

[Enlace](http://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/Delphi/351083-Como-hacer-un-CASE.html), [Enlace Delphi Basics (inglés)](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Case)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Hola Marc , deberías leer [ask] y [answer] ya que hay preguntas que no se deben responder (por ejemplo [esta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLIJU.png)). Tienen muy mala calidad o no son aceptables en el sitio y por tanto las respuestas tampoco. Se que intentas ayudar pero hay que seguir lo estipulado en las normas del sitio. Un saludo